# Is there any way to set post parameters?

Tags: symfony1

Is there any way to set post parameters?

When i submit a form I would like to set a variable (that I give a value dynamically) as a post parameter.

Is that possible?

sf 1.4

Comment: You say you're giving it a value dynamically... where and when: via JS when the user is filling out the form? In the backend after submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. It depends what you're actually trying to achieve.

Post parameters in php are stored in the `$_POST` super global, which just a global array as far as your php code is concerned. So you could do the following:

```
$_POST['my_key'] = $value;
```

This method can also be used to manipulate posted values. But I'd there is a serious issue with you design if you need to add post variables.

Comment: Thanks, you said: "But I'd there is a serious issue with you design if you need to add post variables." Why?

Comment: Because in web development, unlike desktop or mobile development, you have a request life cycle. You should work with it not against it. Also, the `$_POST` is a super global, and as a php developer you should know that globals are very bad practice. So if you find yourself relying on them it's usually a good sign to reevaluate what you're doing as there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking but if you are using javascript to set a variable then add it as a hidden field which your javascript would set which would then be sent with the form.

If you mean that you want to set give a field a default value then you can do that in the form class

```
class myForm extends sfForm
{
  public function configure()
  {

    $this->setDefault('fieldName', 5);
  }
}
```